# On a Visualforce page, input field revert to original values after changed

Tags: apex-code, visualforce

I have an apex list on a visualforce page. When I click the save button, the list is double the actual list when it enters the save function . . . causing a duplicate object in the list. It's something weird, 27 rows are displayed but 54 are returned in the save function. Here is my save code:

```
        <apex:commandButton id="saveButtons" value="Save" rerender="saveButtons" status="loading" >
            <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!saveStaffing}" rerender="saveButtons, error" status="loading">
            </apex:actionSupport>
        </apex:commandButton>
```

Anyone see this behavior before?

Comment: Post your controller

Answer (score 0):

There was an onchange function that rerendered the pageblocktable that caused the values to refresh before clicking save.